# When to use which condition number? (which norm)?

Tags: matrices, euclidean-geometry, normed-spaces, matrix-decomposition

The condition number is used to determine how sensitive `b` is to changes in `A` in the equation `Ax=b`.

The condition number can be measured by the the ratio of max/min singular values.  And, it can also be measured by `norm(A)*norm(A^-1)`.

However, I've never found a satisfactory justification for which norm to use.  The 2-norm, or the 1-norm?

Thanks.

Comment: If you specifically want the ratio of max/min singular values, then you want to use the $2$-norm.  In particular, we have
$$
\|A\|_2 = \sigma_{max}(A)
$$

Comment: Yes, I know those are the same.  But, if you don't know/care if you need the singular values, then what do you use?  And how do you know what to use?

Comment: You may want to check [this](http://www.rejonesconsulting.com/CS210_lect07.pdf).

Comment: It just depends on the context.  The $1$-norm is better for linear programming, compressed sensing, and anything involving sharp corners.  The $2$-norm is better for anything where inner products or calculus is involved.

Comment: That being said, everything you can do with one you *can* do with the other, with enough manipulation.

Comment: Also, since the matrix norms are equivalent, so are the condition numbers. It is just matter of (dimension depending) constants.

Comment: @thanasissdr, that document has several errors, one of which being that the condition number is defined as norm(A)*norm(A)^-1, which would always be 1.  The inverse is on the outside, where it should be on the inside.

Comment: @Hunle I didn't check if there are any errors, but the condition number can be evaluated as: $\kappa(A) = \|A\|\cdot \|A^{-1}\|$. Which page is the error? Ok, I just noticed it! That's a typo!